Angular Material Add transparent color to Row on Hover
I have an Angular Material mat-mdc-table. I want a greyish background color when I hover on a row.
.mat-mdc-row:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
} 

This works, but it overlaps with the white from parent and creates a third color in the padding.

I want an uniform color for my hover row. I don't know why this transparency is applied twice. Just surrounding white and the row's greyish.

I tried to use hex color background-color: #0000000A; but no success.
In browser I identified this CSS affects it:

.mat-mdc-table tbody, 
.mat-mdc-table tfoot, 
.mat-mdc-table thead, 
.mat-mdc-cell, 
.mat-mdc-footer-cell, 
.mat-mdc-header-row, 
.mat-mdc-row, 
.mat-mdc-footer-row, 
.mat-mdc-table 
.mat-mdc-header-cell {
    background-color: inherit;
}


My row has padding of 16px and it seems the padding has this color, but in theory should be the same with tags' content color.


issue not reproducible on stackblitz please replicate the issue and share back the stackblitz, or share a stackblitz with the issue happening

I changed to mat-row tag and reproduced it.
table-basic.example.html L.31
 to ..
stackblitz. In my app I use mat-table, mat-row tags without <table, th, tr>. I don't know if its bad, it was started this way,

Could you try exactly how it is in the stackblitz and see if it fixes the issue. <mat-row>..</mat-row> is an invalid element and mostly it wont work!

In my app even with tags <table, th, tr> it reproduces. The color is applied correctly when i uncheck CSS style from browser like in bullet point 2 in question. In both cases with  or .

please share your html if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens

You can try using the following css in your styles.scss file
.mat-mdc-row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
  .mat-mdc-cell {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

